# Using leaflet-vue-3 How do I open a specific existing popup from a button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a whole bunch of markers on a leaflet-vue map

```
   <l-marker
        v-for="station in stations"
        :lat-lng="[station.lat, station.lon]"
        :options="{title: station.stationname}"
        autoPanOnFocus="true"
        keyboard="true"
        @click="closeAll()"
    >

 <l-icon :icon-size="[15,15]" :icon-url="'/img/bus.png'"/>
 <l-popup>
 .....
 </l-popup>
</l-marker>
```

How do I write a method which will identify and open a specific popup programatically when a button is clicked?

Comment: What does *"a method which will identify open a specific popup programatically"* mean? More specifically, what does *"a specific popup"* mean? What is specific about it? How is it related to the clicked marker? Why does it have to be a specific popup and not the same popup, with dynamically injected content and position? Before deciding on how to do it, you have to clarify what needs to be done.

Comment: @tao
What does "a method which will identify open a specific popup programatically" mean?



There are over 500 starions mapped to the map using markers, as shown above. Each marker contains a popup. I need to be able to choose one from within a method which is clicked "to view the next stop." I just need to know how to fire the open popup event on a different popup than the one that's currently open. (in the script tag), center the user over it, and open it to be viewed.  I don't think there's anything beyond that to explain.

Comment: @tao I imagine that the process would involve dynamically assigning each one a name or attribute of some sort, and then make a call to a Leaflet function which opens that popup, but I don't know what the syntax is to identify one by such an attribute.

Comment: @tao If it was you, please remove your vote to close this question. Totally uncalled for. The question had plenty of context to solve it.

Comment: My vote states this question does not have enough context to be answerable, in my opinion. Since this statement is true, the vote is entirely called for. The only way I'm going to retract it is if you add enough detail/context to change my opinion. Ideally, you should also document your research efforts. Have you tried [layer.bindTooltip](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer-bindtooltip).

Comment: @tao I found my answer. Thanks for your help... 

The answer was to use refs on the marker and call the openPopup function on the ref from the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is to use refs, and call the ref's value.leafletObject.openPopup() function.

To create refs in Vue3 Composition API, assign the ref to the tag using template refs for v-for as such

```
        <l-marker
        v-for="station in stations"
        ref="stationRefs"
        :lat-lng="[station.lat, station.lon]"
        :options="{title: station.stationname}"
        autoPanOnFocus="true"
        keyboard="true"
        @click="closeAll()"
    >
```

Define the v-for ref in your script.

```
import { ref } from "vue";

const stationRefs = ref([])
```

And call the openPopup from a method:

```
function nextStop(stops, station, stations, currentStop, itinerary) {
    let nextStop = stops.find((stop) => stop.itinerary_id == itinerary.id && stop.order == currentStop.order + 1);
    let nextStation = stations.find((station) => station.id == nextStop.station_id);
    if (nextStop) {

        let nextStopMarker = stationRefs.value.find((marker) => marker.options.title == nextStation.stationname);

        nextStopMarker.leafletObject.openPopup();

    } else {
        swal.fire({
            title: "No Next Stop",
            text: "There are no more stops for this itinerary",
            icon: "warning",
            button: "OK"
        });
    }
}
```